# <tr> not showing border for cms page

Tags: html, css, html-table, border, prestashop

For Prestashop I made a custom CMS page, the page has a table which consist of tr's and td's within the table.

On the tr I want a full table-width border bottom.

First of all in the cms page (source code) if I add a table-row without any data/information it just removes it even if I save my code.

So I did put fake copy in the table-data so that prestashop cms page doesn't remove it by-self.

No i want to only display the tr and hide the td within the tr, because ,i have a border on the tr i want to display in full width of the table. 
For some reason my border does not display. Only when un-hiding the td it display the border but then it shows the text i dont want to show.

**Code:**

```
<tr class="menu-border">
 <td><p>text fake</p>
 </td>
 <td><p>text fake</p>
 </td>
 <td><p>text fake</p>
 </td>
</tr>
```

**css:**

```
tr.menu-border {
 margin-bottom: 10%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
 width:100%;
 line-height: 20px;
 margin-top: 10%;
}

tr.menu-border td p{
 display: none;
}
```

So using p tags within the td and then hiding the p tage works but i cant put any margin on the td or tr. If i do it just does not do anyting. Why is this?

Comment: Hello. Did you tryed inline styles??

Comment: Hi, no i did not, and i would prefer not to. If you want me to put style on the html itself i really dont want to do that, for time while i used empty tr with empty td for spacing.

Comment: Just remember that when you save CMS pages Prestashop do some validation and sanitize code according to it own rules. So, in some cases you will have no other option. Good luck.

Comment: Okay cool thanks for that! just the thing is im building an responsive website, so with inline styles its always there , and because my css does not read for td and tr i cant overwrite with media query, but still thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Set the collapsing borders model for a table:

```
table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr{
 border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

This border-collapse method only to show the border of the table.

i think this will help you.

Comment: thanks, but no this did not help me i have tried it, and it was actually implemented without me adding it. I ended up adding p tags to the td and only hide the p tags , this was my solution, but for some reason using margins on the tr or td does not work because i need spacing?